# How to autofill formulas in excel in python?

Tags: python, excel

I am trying to autofill the formula in column D, the image is the expected output.
[image]

My code is as follows. As you can see, I am trying to use a loop and list to complete the action.

```
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook

#Pick the excel file I want to edit.
file_source =r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\BB\Data.xlsx'
#The number of items in column "iso2"
row_len = len(pd.read_excel(file_source,sheet_name='new_sheet', usecols=['iso2']))

#Make the list of formula which I want to autofill in column "iso2" in excel file.
row_len_list=[]
for i in range(row_len):
    j=str(i)
    row_len_list.append(j)
index_formula_list=[]
for x in row_len_list[2:len(row_len_list)]:
    #The formula
    k='=VLOOKUP(A'+x+',old_sheet!A:G,7,0)+200/C'+x
    index_formula_list.append(k)

#load excel file
workbook = load_workbook(filename=file_source)

#Pick the sheet "new_sheet"
ws4 = workbook["new_sheet"]    

#Autofill the formula
for g in range(2,row_len):
    for o in index_formula_list:
        ws4.cell(row=g,column=4).value=o
        workbook.save(filename=file_source)
```

However, it is stuck in a loop and never ends. Please help me find the bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please find below the updated code. I reduced some of the code as you don't need the `read_excel` and separate loops for creation of the arrays, etc. Hope this works....

```
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook

#Pick the excel file I want to edit.
file_source =r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\BB\Data.xlsx'

#load excel file
workbook = load_workbook(filename=file_source)

#Pick the sheet "new_sheet"
ws4 = workbook["new_sheet"]    

#Get length of col A
row_len=len(ws4['A'])

#Autofill the formula
for g in range(2,row_len+1):
    k='=VLOOKUP(A'+str(g)+',old_sheet!A:G,7,0)+200/C'+str(g)
    ws4.cell(row=g,column=4).value=k

workbook.save(filename=file_source)
```

**Output of new_sheet after running code**

[image]

Comment: the `len(ws4['A'])` works from openpyxl v2.4 onwards.  If you have older version, might need to use `max_rows`